# Chrome Native Messaging using Executable Jar file

Tags: java, chrome-native-messaging

I have created a Chrome extension with the nativeMessaging permission added to the manifest.

I am opening a port to the native messaging host.

The manifest for my native messaging host points to an executable jar file.

When I launch my extension, there are no errors, the connection seems fine, but the code in my jar file never seems to run. (For testing I show a new JFrame that is created in the main() method. When double-clicking the jar file it shows the JFrame. But when running the jar file via Chrome Native Messaging, the JFrame doesn't show up.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: y'ever succeed getting this to work?

Comment: Never did succeed with the Java program. I ended up using a different language.

Comment: @HairOfTheDog I've succesfully created one. I can help if you're still interested.

Comment: @farukdgn Can you please tell me how can i run jar file with manifest file

Comment: @HarshaXsoad I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

do you have uppercase letters in your mainfest name ?
i had this issue+same symptoms and this fixed it for me 
(although i get a different error now)

{
  "name": "com.google.chrome.example.echoUppercase", <- wont work
  ....

"name": "com.google.chrome.example.echouppercase", <- works
}

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work by letting chrome start a bat file with the following content:

```
@echo off
java -jar your_file.jar %*
```

The echo off was a detail which took me some time to figure out.

Comment: BAT - file will not send text back to the Google chrome. this is wrong and many people will waste time doing this way. please post how to run the jar straight from the json.

Comment: The example from chrome is also a .bat that start a python program. Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this using a Java executable wrapper (I used [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)).

This is the manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "com.your.application",
    "description": "Your description.",
    "path": "path\\to\\wrapped\\java\\host.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
        "chrome-extension://idofyourchromeextension/"
    ]
}
```

This is the native host application I wrapped:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class ChromeHandler
{
    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputStream input = System.in;
        try
        {
            System.in.available();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return;
        }
        char receivedChar;
        try{
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("PathToTextFile");
            while((receivedChar = (char) input.read()) != -1)
            {
                output.write(receivedChar);
                //My messages only have the '}' character at the end.
                if(receivedChar == '}')
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response mate. thank you i'm lost without working java implementation. will try it ASAP.

Comment: And by the way what is "socket" ?. It is undefined.

Comment: i Commented socket and tried your solution but it still gives me "Error when communicating with the native messaging host" error. Were you able to get it working successfully. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: @HarshaXsoad Yes, that worked successfully. I forgot to remove `socket` part while I was editing for you. Make sure your manifest file and registry entry are correct and consistent. Check `allowed_origins` carefully.

Comment: Thanks mate.... however i picked c++ for my project since this didn't work for me either. But surely it might be some other reason since this code is working for you. i will surely give another try with this later to find about what is wrong. thank you for your help.